# How to fetch imagesfrom json and place it in carousel? Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am fetching all the details from a json file but unable to parse the images object and place it in a carousel slider.
This is my json response

```
{
    "status": true,
    "record": [
        {
            "adid": "44",
            "adsubcatid": "5",
            "aduserid": "37",
            "adname": "vhvhvuf",
            "adcoverimg": "http://codecell.in/girrivi/assets/adcover/scaled_image_picker4508569292934546411.jpg",
            "addesc": "vhvyv",
            "ads_price": "9090",
            "ads_location": "Bengaluru",
            "created_date": "23/10/2020",
            "user_name": "nife",
            "images": "http://codecell.in/girrivi/assets/adimgs/scaled_image_picker4508569292934546411.jpg,http://codecell.in/girrivi/assets/adimgs/scaled_image_picker45085692929345464111.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

And i need to parse this images object.

```
"images": "http://codecell.in/girrivi/assets/adimgs/scaled_image_picker4508569292934546411.jpg,http://codecell.in/girrivi/assets/adimgs/scaled_image_picker45085692929345464111.jpg"
```

This is how i'm fetching the json

```
String images;
Future<String> getProductDetails() async {
    String productDetailsUrl = Constant.productDetailsUrl+widget.id;
    Map<String, String> headers = {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'};

    final response = await http.get(productDetailsUrl, headers: headers);
    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
      setState(() {
        price = jsonResponse['record'][0]['ads_price'];
        title = jsonResponse['record'][0]['adname'];
        description = jsonResponse['record'][0]['addesc'];
        location = jsonResponse['record'][0]['ads_location'];
        publishedOn = jsonResponse['record'][0]['created_date'];
        postedBy = jsonResponse['record'][0]['user_name'];
        adId = jsonResponse['record'][0]['adid'];
        postedById = jsonResponse['record'][0]['aduserid'];
        images = jsonResponse['record'][0]['images'];
      });
    }
  }
```

And this is how I'm placing the images in carousel

```
Carousel(
                  images: [
                    NetworkImage(images == null
                        ? "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ac/No_image_available.svg/600px-No_image_available.svg.png"
                        : carImg)
                  ],
                  dotSize: 4.0,
                  dotSpacing: 15.0,
                  dotColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
                  indicatorBgPadding: 5.0,
                  borderRadius: true,
                  moveIndicatorFromBottom: 180.0,
                  noRadiusForIndicator: true,
                )
```

Comment: *"And i need to parse this images object."* - so you have a `String` with multiple urls separated by `,` - to split it into a `List<String>` read official [String](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String-class.html) class documentation

Comment: But now its coming as ```type 'List<String>' is not a subtype of type 'String'```

Comment: can you show how you split the images String?

Comment: ```images.split(',')``` and placed this inside ```List<String> carImg = images.split(',');```

Comment: so you have `List<String> carImg;` and `carImg = images.split(',');` does not work?

Comment: No its not working

Comment: If i ```print(cars); ``` then all the elements in that object are getting printed inside an array and ```print(cars.length);``` i am getting the actual length of the elements present inside it

Comment: But also I'm getting an error as ```type 'List<String>' is not a subtype of type 'String'```

Comment: inside NetworkImage, it requires a String, you're putting carImg, which is a List<String> there. You should put the element of carImg, which is carImg[0], carImg[1],...

Comment: Yes its working if i give predefined index, but how can i dynamically increment the index?

Comment: i put a solution below, check if it help your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for..in function when you want to apply a List:

```
images: [
  for(var img in carImg)
    return NetworkImage(images == null
       ? "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ac/No_image_available.svg/600px-No_image_available.svg.png"
       : img);
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could something like this,

```
images: images == null  ?
           [ NetworkImage("LOADING IMAGE HERE") ] :
           images.split(',').map((e) => 
                                   NetworkImage(e)
                                   ).toList();
```

Refer: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/split.html